# drawing lines using asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i ve implemented shortest path algorithm on 1 city in asp.net and now i wanted to show the lines between the points selected in shortest path.how it can be done using asp.net?

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you give some more information? How do you "draw" the cities to begin with?

Comment: Are you talking about some 3rd paty maps like Google Maps?

Answer (score 1):

well there's two parts to this question: how do you realize your visualization in HTML, and then how do you ASP.NET to render the HTML that does that. so the first part is completely ASP.NET-independent. you could use javascript for the plotting - if you google for "plotting javascript", you find a bunch of libraries. if this is what you want, write a static HTML page creating the desired output, then think about how you can create the corresponding commands programmatically.